Batch to read Kernel-Power event from System Event Viewer log?
I'm trying to read system status messages to make some decisions in my existing batch files.
For example I really need to know:

if the system is on because it woke from sleep, or if it was cold booted up via button or network etc.
the time at which (or how long ago) lastwake from sleep happened.

I can't find this info with powercfg commands.
And more broadly, would be nice if I could just read from the system log any message and when it was triggered.
Is this possible / accessible via cmd / bat? Can you query all the e.g. Kernel-Power events? Nothing comes up on SO about this.

If you downvote this, please explain what is so bad in my thinking, or lack of knowledge, so I can correct it.

I'm not the one who downvoted, but I suspect it's because your question is not really on-topic here.  It doesn't appear to be about batch file programming, it appears to be about finding a command that you could type into the command prompt.  The fact that you'll later call it from a batch file doesn't change the fact that your question isn't about batch programming (labels, conditionals, loops, variable expansion)

Possible.. My intention was to ask "how can I get this info, in a batch file". Same as if I had asked how can I get this info in a .net project. But I guess this could have also been a superuser question.

On my Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3527]: powercfg.exe /lastwake could return (some ad-hoc examples):

if the system is on because it was cold booted up:

Wake History Count - 0


if the system is on because it woke from sleep by Power Button:

Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Fixed Feature
    Power Button


if the system is on because it woke from sleep by a mouse click:

Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_7AE0&SUBSYS_7D461462&REV_11\3&11583659&0&A0
    Friendly Name: Intel(R) USB 3.20 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.20 (Microsoft)
    Description: USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
    Manufacturer: Generic USB xHCI Host Controller

The time at which lastwake from sleep happened:
wmic path Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE "logfile='system' and SourceName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter' and EventCode=1" Get Message /Value | findstr /I "Time"

or
wmic path Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE "logfile='system' and SourceName='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter' and EventCode=1" Get TimeGenerated

Unfortunately, both above commands could produce a huge output which is hard to parse in cmd or in a .cmd script.
I'd recommend calling PowerShell commands as follows (easy to parse even in cmd):
powershell -noprofile -command "$x=Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Information -InstanceId 1 -Source Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter -After $(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastBootUpTime) -Newest 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TimeGenerated; if ($x) {$x.ToString()} else {''}"


10.05.2024 16:35:46


Note: neglected the imponderable difference between TimeGenerated of an event and real Wake Time…

Assuming there is no elegant way to do this, I will use Task Scheduler, and make an Event based task for each system event I'm looking for, and create flag files . Then my scripts that run at unrelated times, will browse for the flags.. But that's a bit like scratching your left ear with your right foot...
I assume it's also possible to dump or find this system log somewhere on disk and crawl through it... But that's not easier without an API/queries.
What I mean by elegant way:

some windows api for database/log query: ?
some external tool: I saw in a decade old post elsewhere, that some log parser tool, perhaps this microsoft Log Parser, has some API for querying events - but can no longer find any docs.


Now you mention API.  Yes, there definitely is one.  No one offered that as an answer to your original question because batch files can't call API functions.  Native API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/querying-for-events and .NET API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery   The latter can be used directly from Powershell (but still not from batch)

Hmm, well about the API from batch, I assumed you could call some exe (or maybe some powershell) with some query arg, and it would give you back the result you're looking for .. Thanks! I will have a look.
